# How to Combine LocalizedStrings and ResourceDictionary tags in the Application.Resources of the App.xaml file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I would like to use a Style file  as well as a LocalizedStrings file as  resources, in a Windows Phone 8 application, using the App.xaml.

I know that to add a style file as a resource  we can use:

```
<Application.Resources> 
    <ResourceDictionary> 
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Resources/Styles.xaml" /> 
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
    </ResourceDictionary> 
</Application.Resources>
```

and to declare a LocalizedStrings as a resource we can use:

```
<Application.Resources> 
    <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Localizzazione" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/> 
</Application.Resources>
```

Both work well in my app individually. But I have some issues when trying to use both resources at the same time.

Visual Studio prevent me to add the LocalizedStrings tag above the ResourceDictionary tag, asking me for a key, and VS also prevent me to add the LocalizedString tag inside the ResourceDictionnary tag. But VS is quiet when I do the following:

```
<Application.Resources> 
    <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Localizzazione" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/> 
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="MyAppDict"> 
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Resources/Styles.xaml" /> 
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
    </ResourceDictionary> 
</Application.Resources>
```

But when running the app I got an `XamlParseException` with Additional Info: Failed to assign to property `System.Windows.ResourceDictionnary.Source`.

So do you have any idea on how to combine those two resources in the App.xaml file?

Comment: Are you getting any exception or error? if exception means can you add the message you got in the exception?

Comment: I get a XamlParseException when starting the app.

Comment: In My app I too got the exception, But I created a Resource file wit the help of Blend there is no exception. But I don't know the exact reason. Create a Resource File using Blend, I hope it will help for you too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add both using below code.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="./Resources/ThemeResources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Localizzazione" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>            
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I am using both in my application & it will not showing any exception there.

Comment: Thx for your answer, i tried it but i've got the same error. maybe I am doing something else wrong, but I got the same `XamlParseException`

Comment: Have you put your Resource file into Resource folder??

Answer (score 0):

I followed Kunjan Patel's idea but still didn't work. So I tried "LocalizedStrings" before the "ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries" and it worked! See below.

```
<Application.Resources> 
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="MyAppDict">
    <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Localizzazione" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Resources/Styles.xaml" /> 
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
</ResourceDictionary>
```